# TextView color selector changes color only on press and not select

Tags: android, xml, colors, selector, drawable

I'm using a custom view for SlidingTabLayout. I've set a drawable(selector) for the text's color , but for some reason it only changes on tab press and not on select.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_color_selector"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"/>
```

the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/white" />     
<item android:state_active="true" android:color="@color/white" /> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white" />
<item android:color="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

Hope. It will help you